Bootstrap Table Not Responsive
I have a page that displays a bootstrap table. Unfortunately, the table does not become responsive. I have wrapped my table around a div with the "responsive table" class so that it is always responsive.
Full

Resize Medium
At this point I expect the table to become responsive with a horizontal scroll bar, but it does not.

Resize Small
At this point the "Contacts" area and "Coming Up" area is forced to wrap below the side bar and the table finally becomes responsive. I was hoping the table would have become responsive before the "Contacts" area and "Coming Up" area wrapped under the side bar.


Code
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="keywords">
    <meta name="description">
    <title>
        Contacts
    </title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Razor.Portal.styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/css/site.css">

</head>

<body>
<header>
    
    <script src="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow">
        
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9">
    <img src="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/data/logos/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9.png" alt="Logo" class="float-start img-fluid">
</a>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2" style="background-color: #1C4932">
            
<div  class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 mb-auto min-vh-100" style="background-color: #1C4932">
    <a  href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
        <span  class="fs-5 d-none d-sm-inline">Menu</span>
    </a>
    <ul  class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
        <li >
            <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard">
                <i  class="fa-thin fa-gauge" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span  class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard">
                <i  class="fa-thin fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span  class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Email</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings">
                <i  class="fa-thin fa-chart-bar" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span  class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Reports</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings">
                <i  class="fa-thin fa-gear" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span  class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Settings</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings">
                <i  class="fa-thin fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span  class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Profile</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="">
                <i  class="fa-thin fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span  class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Help</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Account/Signout">
                <i  class="fa-thin fa-right-from-bracket" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span  class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Signout</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



        </div>
            
        <div class="col content-background">
            <div class="row">
                
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="mt-2 mobilecrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9">Home</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings">Settings</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings/Organization">Organization</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Contacts</li>
    </ol>
</nav>


                <div class="row">
    <div class="col">


    </div>
</div>
 


                <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    </div>
</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="row gx-2">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-9">
                    <div class="p-3 backgroundWhite">
                        
<h4>Contacts</h4>
<hr>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>John Smith</td>
                                <td>someemail@gmail.com</td>
                                <td>(480) 345-2383</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group float-end" role="group">
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary text-white edit" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings/Organization/Contacts/Edit?email=someemail@gmail.com"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-sm" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                        <button class="btn btn-success text-white details" data-email="someemail@gmail.com">
                                            <i class="fas fa-list fa-sm" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger text-white delete" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings/Organization/Contacts/Delete?email=someemail@gmail.com"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-sm" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" class="border-0">
                                    <a class="btn btn-success float-end" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings/Organization/Contacts/Add"><i class="fas fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Add</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>






                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <div class="p-3 backgroundWhite">
                        
<div class="row min-vh-100">
    <div class="col-6"><h6>Coming Up</h6></div>
    <div class="col-6 text-end">
        <i class="fa-thin fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; <span class="align-text-top" style="font-size: x-small"><a href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings">View Calendar</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

    

</body></html>

Some additional CSS
.mobilecrumb ol.breadcrumb {
    flex-wrap: unset;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

    .mobilecrumb ol.breadcrumb > li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
/* breakdown to hide it on small devices */
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    .mobilecrumb ol.breadcrumb > li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .mobilecrumb ol.breadcrumb > li:last-child:before {
        content: var(--bs-breadcrumb-divider, "/ ... /");
    }

    .mobilecrumb ol.breadcrumb > li:last-child {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
}

.content-background {
    background: url('/data/dust_scratches.png');
}

.backgroundWhite {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

Any help guidance would be appreciated. I am sure I am doing something wrong.

Bootstrap's responsiveness is limited to providing horizontal scrolling.  That's it.  I don't see anything that could be deemed as a bug in what Bootstrap promises.

@JoséRamírez shouldn't I expect horizontal scrolling when I resize the screen to a medium, as opposed to the text wrapping to a new line within the column?

Only if your markup is set up for that, but your responsive markup seems to be allowing the content to drop one row.  This, I would say, has nothing to do with the table, but try it out:  Exchange the table for something else.  Does it drop to the next row?  If yes, the table has no effect on this issue and you should look to solve this problem first, before seeing how the table reacts, I would say.

You can have your side bar as full height by setting your menu and contact columns to be complementary: make the menu setup as col-2 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-xl-2 (not col-auto for the smallest size) and the contact setup as  col-10 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-xl-10.
The table width will be 100% of the available space and the content of each cell will be wrapped so long as there is space. There is no connection between the text wrapping in a cell and what breakpoint you’ve selected. If you don’t want the text in a cell to wrap, apply .text-nowrap to the cell. If you want to apply nowrap based on screen width, you can create your own .text-nowrap-md using media queries, for example.


.mobilecrumb ol.breadcrumb {
    flex-wrap: unset;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.mobilecrumb ol.breadcrumb>li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* breakdown to hide it on small devices */
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    .mobilecrumb ol.breadcrumb>li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .mobilecrumb ol.breadcrumb>li:last-child:before {
        content: var(--bs-breadcrumb-divider, "/ ... /");
    }

    .mobilecrumb ol.breadcrumb>li:last-child {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
}

.content-background {
    background: url('/data/dust_scratches.png');
}

.backgroundWhite {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9">
            <img src="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/data/logos/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9.png" alt="Logo" class="float-start img-fluid">
        </a>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-xl-2" style="background-color: #1C4932">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 mb-auto min-vh-100" style="background-color: #1C4932">
                <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
                    <span class="fs-5 d-none d-sm-inline">Menu</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard">
                            <i class="fa fa-gauge" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Email</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings">
                            <i class="fa fa-chart-bar" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Reports</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings">
                            <i class="fa fa-gear" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Settings</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings">
                            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Profile</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="">
                            <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Help</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link px-0 align-middle text-white" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Account/Signout">
                            <i class="fa fa-right-from-bracket" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Signout</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-xl-10 content-background">
            <div class="row">
                <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="mt-2 mobilecrumb">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings">Settings</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings/Organization">Organization</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Contacts</li>
                    </ol>
                </nav>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row gx-2">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
                    <div class="p-3 backgroundWhite">
                        <h4>Contacts</h4>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table table-striped">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>1</td>
                                                    <td class="text-nowrap">John Smith</td>
                                                    <td>someemail@gmail.com</td>
                                                    <td class="text-nowrap">(480) 345-2383</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="btn-group float-end" role="group">
                                                            <a class="btn btn-primary text-white edit" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings/Organization/Contacts/Edit?email=someemail@gmail.com"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-sm" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                            <button class="btn btn-success text-white details" data-email="someemail@gmail.com">
                                                                <i class="fas fa-list fa-sm" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                            </button>
                                                            <a class="btn btn-danger text-white delete" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings/Organization/Contacts/Delete?email=someemail@gmail.com"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-sm" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="5" class="border-0">
                                                        <a class="btn btn-success float-end" href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings/Organization/Contacts/Add"><i class="fas fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Add</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-2 mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <div class="p-3 backgroundWhite">
                        <div class="row min-vh-100">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h6>Coming Up</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 text-end">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; <span class="align-text-top" style="font-size: x-small"><a href="/586E6FD5-5421-433D-BC0D-9137281AAAC9/Dashboard/Settings">View Calendar</a></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Question <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78987874/bootstrap-table-not-responsive">Stack Overflow</a></p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>




Thank you very much! Your explanation was very helpful
